# Azure notification hub - Apple (APNS) does not load

Tags: azure, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

As requested by azure support on twitter, I'm posting this issue here:

When I try to configure the certificates used for the Apple Push Notification service (APNS) in our Notification Hub settings using https://portal.azure.com/ 
the "blade" pops up but just displays the loading animation forever.

It used to work about a month ago.

Here is a video of the issue (not much going on):
https://webmshare.com/0KLEz

I've tried the following web browsers but the result was the same:

- Google Chrome Version 60.0.3112.101 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Opera 47.0.2631.34 (PGO)
- Microsoft Edge 40.15063.0.0

The other services (Google (GCM), etc.) work fine.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you retry and check if it works now. I tried to do the same on Chrome browser and it seemed to work fine. Are there any specific repro steps you have. What did you do before it stopped working? Can you try to create a new hub and see if it works?

Comment: I created a new hub and this one works / loads fine...
Maybe I'll just migrate everything to the new hub. But still, the issue remains for the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, It can be loaded fine in Microsoft Edge (and Google Chrome) on my side. If possible, you can try to add a new hub and check if same issue appears when you click **Apple (APNS)** option.

[image]

Secondly, I checked [the status history](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/history/) of Microsoft Azure services, I find no status history information for Notification Hub. For Azure portal displaying issues, you can [create an Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to report it.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I didn't know where to find info like that and will check there from now on. My issue wouldn't have been on there, but still it's a first place to look.